# Convert hex-string to integer with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

Note that the problem is not **hex to decimal** but a string of hex values to integer.

Say I've got a sting from a hexdump (eg. '6c 02 00 00') so i need to convert that into actual hex first, and then get the integer it represents... (this particular one would be 620 as an int16 and int32)

I tried a lot of things but confused myself more. Is there a quick way to do such a conversion in python (preferably 3.x)?

Comment: So, just as a reminder - don't mangle your input data more than it already is.  (i.e. don't add extra spaces between the digits) - the codecs + struct approach I added at the end of my answer could have struck others (and myself) as the "one obvious way to do it" where it not for the spaces

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**update** From Python 3.7 on, bytes.from_hex will ignore whitespaces  -so, the straightforward thing to do is parse the string to a bytes object, and then see then as an integer:

```
In [10]: int.from_bytes(bytes.fromhex("6c 02 00 00"), byteorder="little")
Out[10]: 620
```

**original answer**

Not only that is a string, but it is in little endian order - meanng that just removing the spaces, and using `int(xx, 16)` call will work. Neither does it have the actual byte values as 4 arbitrary 0-255 numbers (in which case struct.unpack would work).

I think a nice approach is to swap the components back into "human readable" order, and use the int call - thus:

```
number = int("".join("6c 02 00 00".split()[::-1]), 16)
```

What happens there: the first part of th expession is the `split` - it breaks the string at the spaces, and provides a list with four strings, two digits in each. The [::-1] special slice goes next - it means roughly "provide me a subset of elements from the former sequence, starting at the edges, and going back 1 element at a time" - which is a common Python idiom to reverse any sequence.

This reversed sequence is used in the call to `"".join(...)` - which basically uses the empty string as a concatenator to every element on the sequence - the result of the this call  is "0000026c". With this value, we just call Python's `int` class which accepts a secondary optional paramter denoting the base that should be used to interpret the number denoted in the first argument.

```
>>> int("".join("6c 02 00 00".split()[::-1]), 16)
620
```

Another option, is to  cummulatively add the conversion of each 2 digits, properly shifted to their weight according to their position - this can also be done in a single expression using `reduce`, though a 4 line Python `for` loop would be more readable:

```
>>> from functools import reduce #not needed in Python2.x
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x  + (int(y[1], 16)<<(8 * y[0]) ), enumerate("6c 02 00 00".split()), 0)
620
```

**update** The OP just said he does not actually have the "spaces" in the string - in that case, one can use just abotu the same methods, but taking each two digits instead of the `split()` call:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x  + (int(y[1], 16)<<(8 * y[0]//2) ), ((i, a[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(a), 2)) , 0)
```

(where `a` is the variable with your digits, of course) -
Or, convert it to an actual 4 byte number in memory, usign the hex codec, and unpack the number with struct - this may be more semantic correct for your code:

```
import codecs
import struct
struct.unpack("<I", codecs.decode("6c020000", "hex") )[0]
```

So the approach here is to pass each 2 digits to an actual byte in memory in a bytes object returned by the `codecs.decode` call, and struct to read the 4 bytes in the buffer as a single 32bit integer.

Comment: Thanks, I actually had the dump without the spaces but just added them on here for readability. Anyway I added spaces after every 2 chars and performed your one-liner, and if worked perfectly... I guess I was overcomplicating it by trying to convert it to proper hex and then feed that into fns like bytes.fromhex() and others.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`unhexlify()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify) to convert the hex string to its binary form, and then use [`struct.unpack()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) to decode the **little endian** value into an int:

```
>>> from struct import unpack
>>> from binascii import unhexlify
>>> n = unpack('<i', unhexlify('6c 02 00 00'.replace(' ','')))[0]
>>> n
```

The [format string](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/struct.html#format-strings) `'<i'` means little endian signed integer. You can substitute with `'<I'` or `'<L'` for unsigned int or long (both 4 bytes).

If the data does not contain spaces this simplifies to

```
>>> n = unpack('<i', unhexlify('6c020000'))[0]
```